# Display data form mysql database in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have tried to display data from my Mysql database using Django. The user enters the required data through addSubscriber.html page to save in the database and is redirected to a page 'report.html' where all the data from the table (in this case subscribers) is displayed.

Here are my files: views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views import generic
from .models import Subscribers
from .forms import addSubsForm


@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    user = request.user
    context = {'user': user}
    template = 'dashboard.html'
    return render(request, template, context)



@login_required
def addSubscriber(request):
    template = 'addSubscriber.html'

    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = addSubsForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                f = form.save(commit=False)
                f.save(using='db2')
                data = Subscribers.objects.all()
                return redirect('report', {'entries': data})

    else:
            form = addSubsForm()

    return render(request, template, {'form': form})




@login_required
def report(request):
    context = locals()
    template = 'report.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Subscribers
from django import forms


class addSubsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subscribers
        fields = '__all__'
```

report.html

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}


{% block content %}

 <h2 class="page-header">Subscribers List</h2>


          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Bill Number</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Area</th>
                  <th>Phone Number</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>{% for entries in Subscribers %}
                  <td>{{ entries.billNumber }}</td>
                  <td>{{ entries.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ entries.area }}</td>
                  <td>{{ entries.phoneNumber }}</td>
                  <td>{{ entries.name }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The error when ever I submit the form is:

```
NoReverseMatch at /dashboard/addSubscriber/
Reverse for 'report' with arguments '({'entries': <QuerySet [(1, u'Manish Ojha', u'Jirikhimti', u'9843003979', u'2000', u'21'), (2, u'Manish Ojha', u'Jirikhimti', u'9843003979', u'2000', u'1'), (3, u'Manish Ojha', u'Jirikhimti', u'9843003979', u'2000', u'2'), (4, u'Manish Ojha', u'Jirikhimti', u'9843003979', u'2000', u'3'), (5, u'Manish Ojha', u'Jirikhimti', u'9843003979', u'2000', u'4'), (6, u'Manish Ojha', u'Jirikhimti', u'9843003979', u'2000', u'5'), (7, u'Manish Ojha', u'Jirikhimti', u'9843003979', u'2000', u'6'), (8, u'Manish Ojha', u'Jiri', u'8989', u'989', u'27308472893478'), (9, u'Manish Ojha', u'Jiri', u'8989', u'989', u'27308472893478'), (10, u'Manish Ojha', u'Jiri', u'8989', u'989', u'1'), (11, u'Manish Ojha', u'Jiri', u'8989', u'989', u'1'), (12, u'Manish', u'jklj', u'89890', u'99089', u'8989'), (13, u'Manish', u'jklj', u'89890', u'99089', u'8989'), (14, u'Manish', u'jklj', u'89890', u'99089', u'8989'), (15, u'Manish', u'jklj', u'89890', u'99089', u'8989'), (16, u'Manish', u'jklj', u'89890', u'99089', u'8989'), (17, u'Manish', u'jklj', u'89890', u'99089', u'8989'), (18, u'sdf', u'sdf', u'sdf', u'sdf', u'sdf'), (19, u'sdf', u'sdf', u'sdf', u'sdf', u'sdf'), (20, u'sfdf', u'jh', u'jhj', u'hj', u'hj'), '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>}, 1)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard/report/$']
```

Even these datas were entered a long time ago and already erased from the database they are still displayed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line

```
return redirect('report', {'entries': data}, 1)
```

to

```
return redirect('report')
```

and in report view

```
@login_required
def report(request):
    data = Subscribers.objects.all()
    template = 'report.html'
    return render(request, template, {'entries' : data})
```

and change this line in the html

```
{% for entries in Subscribers %}
```

to

```
{% for entry in entries %}
<td>{{ entry .billNumber }}</td>
```

same for other `tds` also

Comment: Sorry for the `return redirect('report', {'entries': data}, 1)`. the 1 at the end was my mistake. I was experimenting with the code

Comment: The page is redirected to report.html but in report.html the datas from the database is not shown.

Comment: All the datas are displayed, even those which I deleted from the database. The ones I used before. How do I delete these datas?

Comment: delete it from the database as thats the easiest way if you have many data

Comment: I deleted ever data from the database. However, all the data that has been deleted are also shown. How is this possible??

Comment: you have 2 database remember? so you need to check from which database so if you want to use db2 change the query to Subscribers.objects.using('db2').all()

Comment: My god you are a genius. Thanks again bro

Comment: Can you suggest me any book or website where I can learn Django and python and be good as you?

Comment: there is no such book bro, i learnt by making mistakes only, like you only. but you can go through django app documentation, creating your first django app. its good

Comment: doing the same thing. this is my first app. But the documentation is a tough one. God its difficult to be a programmer. however trying my best

Comment: bro remember the start is always the hardest and to be frank bro even i dont know a lot of things of django :)

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for entries in Subscribers %} 
<tr>
    <td>{{ entries.billNumber }}</td>
    <td>{{ entries.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ entries.area }}</td>
    <td>{{ entries.phoneNumber }}</td>
    <td>{{ entries.name }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I think this was also done wrong. Try my code and see if mine works